# OS X Mail Data Detectors - how to format signature

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

Is there any special formatting to get the data detectors show this banner? (When the contact is not in the address book)

[image: New contact info found in this email:]

The data detectors seems to find my signature, and when I click the little arrow button offer to add the contact. But the banner seems to appear at random.

Answer (score 1):

From the behavior I see on my system I am going to say it is looking for full signatures in emails that include phone #s and maybe addresses and emails. If it sees changed information then it pops up.

As far as new contacts it seems to look for the same. I have plenty of emails with no phone or email and that never pops up. Or with emails that have just a name and email address where I can get a drop down arrow but the line you have in your question does not come up.